# Illegal Instructions (core dumped) error on launch of my application in Ubuntu 14.04, how to see dump

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, compiler-options

On Launching my application , i see illegal instruction core dumped on some machines which has ubuntu 14.04. My application is also build in 14.04 , but installing and running in some systems gives such error.

Where does the dump gets saved and how to see the dump. I am assuming it may have some information about what instruction is not supported in that machine .

Answer (score 1):

Core files are not enabled by default on Ubuntu. To do that, run `ulimit -c unlimited`, and let your program crash again. The core file should be generated in the current directory.

Typically I see this for x86 extensions like newer versions of SSE on old hardware. To fix it, the code needs to be recompiled, or the hardware needs to be upgraded.

Comment: once the core dump generated how to see it.. just cat <dumpfile> is good enough?